# How to spy on Apollo Client cache calls for unit testing?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using enzyme to "mount" a component wrapped with `withApollo`, hence it has a `client` object in context that it finds available in the props. The component writes on the client cache using `writeQuery` conditionally, and I am writing a unit test that simulates those conditions, I would like to be able to assert that this cache method has been called with the expected arguments.

Following Apollo-Client guidelines, I am using the  [MockedWrapper](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/testing.html#MockedProvider). I think this would a good place to intercept the client object and replace its `writeQuery` function with a mock function. I do not know how or if it is even possible.

Alternatively, I could ditch the `MockedProvider` and simulate the context entirely, but I do not know the expected object inside the context nor its shape/schema.